# Do you have any worries with liability on SU?

Tags: discussion

If not, why not?  If so, are there certain types of advice (reinstall for example) that you would not give without disclaimer?

Comment: Why single out SU?  Can you not get bad advice on SF or SO?

Comment: (heck, with SU you will *typically* break 1 machine at a time; with SO/SF you could take down a whole enterprise if you mess up spectacularly enough...)

Comment: although, tbh, users on SU will generally be less competent than those on SO and SF (at least, I would hope that those using (especially SF) the other two sites know what they are doing)

Answer (score 14):

Nope. I live blissfully free of such worries. And *you can too*!

#### Steps to live blissfully free of such worries (for Windows users):

1. Open a command prompt (press the start button, click on "Run", type in `cmd`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Type: `FORMAT C: /X`
3. Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: I'll sue you for that!

Comment: This deserves a 'win' tag

Comment: If I could give tags to individual answers, I would give this one a 'win' tag

Comment: This is one of the few things that works on all versions of Windows.

Comment: But the user might have another bootable partition...